# Scripting with "self" in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, nameerror

What is "self" and how can I use it error-free in a Q script?

Example:

```
mc = self.iface.mapCanvas()
```

But when I try to run this in the Console I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Maybe I need to import a specific module of some kind to use 'self'?

Comment: substitute 'self' with 'qgis.utils' in console

Comment: Actually @MaximDubinin 'qgis.utils' instead of 'self' works in the script as well as in the console.  But then my question remains... what is this 'self' that I see people using in scripts?  It doesn't work for me.  Yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`self` refer to the instance of the class you have to load to make any QGIS plugin work e.g [this example file](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins.html#mainplugin-py).

In the console, you don't need the  `self` stuff as you don't use the same loading mechanism as in a QGIS plugin.

`self` isn't specific to QGIS, it's a convention when doing object oriented programming with Python. You can look at some Python course to know more. [This article](https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/) could also help.